# Oracle 12c login credentials for windows built-in user account

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

J just installed a new copy of Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition with following basic install time settings:

- Skip software updates
- install database software only
- single instance database installation
- English language
- Enterprise edition
- use windows built-in account
- install path: C:\Oracle\

The installation went smoth without any critical warnings or errors.
After installation when I start SQL*Plus command line it requires me

```
User Name:
Password:
```

I have not specified any of these during installation. S, what could probably be the credentials?
I tried using my windows log-in user & password to login (Nte: My windows log-in name has a white space in middle as: FirstName LastName) but it issued me an ERROR message as:

```
Enter user-name: ******* ********
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
```

Then I tried using same user name without white space but got another Error message as:

```
Enter user-name: ***************
Enter password:******
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

Is there anywhere I am going wrong? Please suggest me the solution
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

**My suggestions:**

1: First ensure that you have specified ORACLE_SID AND ORACLE_HOME environment variable before trying to login. You can try following commands to set those environment variables:
Put correct path and sid_name for the following commands and insert them system environment variable. Don't forget to check the value of respective environment variable before login attempt.
    ORACLE_BASE=C:\oracle;
    ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE\product\11.2\db_1;
    ORACLE_SID=sid_name_here;
    PATH=$PATH:ORACLE_HOME\bin;
Now, issue should get resolved if you getting trouble because of environment variable.

2: Next, verify the status of listener. See the output of following commands to confirm the status of listener:
    lsnrctl status
    lsnrctl services
Above command show the status of listener and associated service. If you didn't see SID and associated service name, You need to start listener service (i.e. from services.msc).

3: Sometimes, you might be getting this issue because of TNS_ADMIN not setup properly. Configure TNS_ADMIN in system environment variable and also mention in the tnsnames.ora file. Refer [link](http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=2554) for the discussion configuring TNS_ADMIN in windows environment.

Comment: My mistake was that, the database I created had SID='root' instead f 'orcl'

Comment: is this link broken?

Comment: @JuniorM - Seems that http://dbaforums.org have some issue, alternatively you can get help from following URL, Donald Burleson has covered for both LINUX and Windows environment.
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tns_admin.htm